# If I wanted to use Lua for Web Development, how would I go about do it, and should I just use Rails instead?

Tags: frameworks, web, lua

I wanted to get the excitement of learning a new language. I was thinking of developing a site using Lua. My questions and concerns:

1. Should I do it, or should I stick with something like Rails.
2. What do I use to render Lua into dynamic websites?
3. What IDE would I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497874/has-anyone-used-lua-for-web-development

Answer (score 2):

The old lua web framework was kepler; their MVC framework being [orbit](http://keplerproject.github.com/orbit/index.html)

You can also check out [Tir](http://tir.mongrel2.org/)

You can use any 'IDE' you want, most just stick with their favourite (programmer's) text editor. (if it helps, I use sublime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lua for web development. Try the Kepler(http://www.keplerproject.org/). You can use gVIM.